# Python combine multiple lists of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

Ok so i end up with a lot of lists of tuples like so.

```
l1 = [('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 3), ('D', 4), ('E', 5)]
l2 = [('A', 1), ('C', 2), ('F', 8), ('D', 15), ('X',21)]
l3 = [('C', 1), ('F', 4), ('R', 16), ('D', 19), ('Z', 31)]
```

Where in each list has already been sorted by the number.

What i need to do is build a list of tuples which combines information from all lists into a format like this.

```
final_list = [('A', 1, 1, 0), ('B', 2, 0, 0), ('C', 3, 2, 1), ('D', 4, 15, 19), ('E', 5, 0, 0), ('F', 0, 8, 4), ('X', 0, 21, 0), ('R', 0, 0, 16), ('Z', 0, 0, 31)]
```

The most important part being the tuples themselves are in order of name, list one, list two, list three etc and when a letter/name isnt present in a list it has a zero for that lists position.

Is this too complicated, have i programmed myself into a hole?

Comment: you have a typo in first line where 'C' is missing the closing quote

Comment: i have fixed the typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Again!**
More Functional and Compact.

*

```
l1 = [('A', 1, 3), ('B', 2, 5), ('C', 3, 16), ('D', 4, 19), ('E', 5, 20)];
l2 = [('A', 1), ('C', 2), ('F', 8), ('D', 15), ('X',21)];
l3 = [('C', 1), ('F', 4), ('R', 16), ('D', 19), ('Z', 31)]

for k in l1,l2,l3:
    # 'dummy to keep track of tuple size'
    k.append(('dummy',len(k[0][1:])))

dict_lx =  [ dict(map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1:]), l)) for l in l1,l2,l3 ]
sorted_keys = sorted(set(reduce(lambda x,y : x + y.keys(), dict_lx, [])))

final = map(lambda key: tuple(
    [key] + reduce(lambda x,y: x + list(y.get(key, y.get('dummy')[0]*[0])), dict_lx, [])), sorted_keys)

final = filter(lambda x: x[0] != 'dummy', final)
print final
#[('A', 1, 3, 1, 0), ('B', 2, 5, 0, 0), ('C', 3, 16, 2, 1), ('D', 4, 19, 15, 19), ('E', 5, 20, 0, 0), ('F', 0, 0, 8, 4), ('R', 0, 0, 0, 16), ('X', 0, 0, 21, 0), ('Z', 0, 0, 0, 31)]
```

*

Comment: if i wanted this to work with a list of tuples where each tuple was on n length. how would i edit this to work?

Comment: l1 = [('A', 1, 3), ('B', 2, 5), ('C', 3, 16), ('D', 4, 19), ('E', 5, 20)]
l2 = [('A', 1), ('C', 2), ('F', 8), ('D', 15), ('X',21)]
l3 = [('C', 1), ('F', 4), ('R', 16), ('D', 19), ('Z', 31)]

like that for example

Comment: @pancakefacecake: Updated, try it out.

Comment: Damn thats really good, but it isnt quite right. For example on F there should be two zeros at beginning to indicate its missing twice [but i dont think i made it clear thats what i intend] . I think im going to re-plan how i do this program. Thanks for your help though

Comment: @pancakefacecake Updated Again! Try it!

Comment: @pancakefacecake Is there anything else? I'd love to help! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in two steps:

First construct a dict, then construct the final_list

```
from collections import defaultdict

li = [l1, l2, l3, ...]
temp_dict = defaultdict(tuple)
for l in li:
    for e in l:
        temp_dict[e[0]] += (e[1],)

# Got {'A': (1, 1, 0), 'B': (2, 0, 0), ... }

final_list = [(key, ) + temp_dict[key] for key in temp_dict]
```

Tried it in REPL:

```
>>> l1 = [('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 3), ('D', 4), ('E', 5)]
>>> l2 = [('A', 1), ('C', 2), ('F', 8), ('D', 15), ('X',21)]
>>> l3 = [('C', 1), ('F', 4), ('R', 16), ('D', 19), ('Z', 31)]
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> li = [l1, l2, l3,]
>>> temp_dict = defaultdict(tuple)
>>> for l in li:
...     for e in l:
...             temp_dict[e[0]] += (e[1],)
...
>>> temp_dict
defaultdict(<type 'tuple'>, {'A': (1, 1), 'C': (3, 2, 1), 'B': (2,), 'E': (5,), 'D': (4, 15, 19), 'F': (8, 4), 'R': (16,), 'X': (21,), 'Z': (31,)})
>>> final_list = [(key, ) + temp_dict[key] for key in temp_dict]
>>> final_list
[('A', 1, 1), ('C', 3, 2, 1), ('B', 2), ('E', 5), ('D', 4, 15, 19), ('F', 8, 4), ('R', 16), ('X', 21), ('Z', 31)]
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but problem with that is you dont get the zeros in final list, which means i cant use it for rest of my program. Thanks anyway though

Comment: @pancakefacecake So would you rather modify it yourself or should I modify my code?

Comment: I mean i could just ask you but i wouldnt learn anything, if there is any tutorial that is relevant to what you did explaining it that you could link me, i would be grateful. thanks

Comment: @pancakefacecake Which part didn't you understand?

Comment: I dont understand any of it to be honest, i know that a default dict stops errors coming up if searching for a key that doesnt exist, but i dont know how to use them.

Comment: @pancakefacecake https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects, there are many examples in the official doc. I need the value of dict to be a tuple, so I use `defaultdict(tuple)`. I think you don't need to focus on `defaultdict` because with a few more lines of code you could still do the same thing using a regular dict. The vital thing is how to solve this kind of problem, and my advice is, if it's too hard to do it in a single step, do it step by step, which, for this question, is building a `temp_dict`.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not too complicated, although you may wish to consider using a dict of lists (or tuples) keyed by the letter. OTOH, your current setup uses less memory than a dict.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

l1 = [('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 3), ('D', 4), ('E', 5)]
l2 = [('A', 1), ('C', 2), ('F', 8), ('D', 15), ('X',21)]
l3 = [('C', 1), ('F', 4), ('R', 16), ('D', 19), ('Z', 31)]


def main():
    dlist = [dict(u) for u in (l1, l2, l3)]

    keys = sorted(set(sum([d.keys() for d in dlist], [])))

    final = [(key,) + tuple([d.get(key, 0) for d in dlist]) for key in keys]

    for row in final:
        print row


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```